# Is it possible to use a P2PKH output with a schnorr signature?

Tags: schnorr-signatures, p2pkh

I know that Bitcoin has many different transaction output types (P2SH, P2WPKH, P2WSH, P2TR, etc).

And I know that P2PKH is an old transaction output type that has existed since before Segwit and before Taproot.

Is it still possible to create a P2PKH output that works with Schnorr signatures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use Schnorr signatures with old output types.

Current node software evaluating transactions expects an ECDSA signature for an input spending a P2PKH output. Putting a Schnorr signature there would be invalid per the accepted rules. Even if the rules were updated to allow using Schnorr signatures, old node software would always reject a transaction that uses the updated understanding, and this would therefore classify as a hardfork.

Answer (score 2):

No, Schnorr signatures are only used in taproot spends (v1 segwit with 32 byte witness program) as specified in [BIP-342](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0342.mediawiki#specification). This cannot be P2SH wrapped, and are encoded only with Bech32m.

Script path spending of Taproot modifies OP_CHECKSIG(VERIFY) to use Schnorr signatures instead of ECDSA. A new opcode is also made available for batch verification, OP_CHECKSIGADD. This means it is no longer possible to use ECDSA in taproot scripts.